# Function printArray not working properly

Tags: c, arrays

I'm trying to make function that prints array but the output of it is wrong.
Can someone help me please?

This is the code:

```
    #define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
    #include <stdio.h>
    void printArr(int arr[],int size);

    int main()
    {
        int arr1[3] = { 1,2,3 };
        int arr2[5] = { 1,2,3,4,5 };

        printf("arr1: \n");
        printArr(arr1, 3);

        printf("\n\narr2: \n");
        printArr(arr2, 5);
        printf("\n\n");

        return(0);
    }

    void printArr(int arr[], int size)
    {
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < size; i++);
        {
            printf("%d", arr[i]);
        }

}
```

What I get is:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the semi-colon at the of `for`:

```
for (i = 0; i < size; i++);
                          ^^^
```

That makes the `for` loop run `size` times and executes the *block* after that. But by that time, `i` value is equal to `size`. This leads to out of bound access, which is [*undefined behaviour*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Clearly, this is not what you intention was.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't notice the " ; ".